# WPF How to Set selecteditem of bound combobox in a listview with different itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have a ComboBox on a ListView item, the ComboBox uses one ObservableCollection and the ListView uses another. How can I set the selecteditem of the ComboBox to the value of a column in the listview item?

The ListView uses a GridView defined as follows:

```
        <GridView x:Key="manage_calls_gridView">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MCName}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Allocated To" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MCPostCode}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Post Code" Width="180" CellTemplate="{StaticResource manage_calls_pcode}" />
    </GridView>
```

With the ComboBox defined in a DataTemplate as follows:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="manage_calls_pcode">
        <ComboBox Width="180" DropDownClosed="mc_pcode_DropDownClosed" DataContext="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LookUpCollection_6}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Desc"
                  />
    </DataTemplate>
```

This is the class the ComboBox uses for its ObservableCollection (LookUpCollection_6)

```
        public class LookUp
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the class the ListView, containing the ComboBox, uses for its ObservableCollection (SalesAgentList)

```
        public class SalesAgentRec
    {
        public string MCName { get; set; }
        public string MCPostCode { get; set; }
        public string MCSource { get; set; }
        public string MCUid { get; set; }
        public string MCRecs { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to set the selected item/value of the ComboBox to the value of MCPostCode.

Thanks in advance,

Steve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in your class / data model
And drop the datacontext

```
public class SalesAgentRec
    {
        public string MCName { get; set; }
        public string MCPostCode { get; set; }
        public string MCSource { get; set; }
        public string MCUid { get; set; }
        public string MCRecs { get; set; }
        public List<LookUpCollection_6> { get; set; }
    }
```

SelecteIndex="{Binding Path=MCPostCode}"

And for a simple ID Desc like that use a Dictionary.  The two properties are Key and Value.

Comment: Hi Blam, I have accepted your reply as the answer as it was the most helpful in getting me on the right track. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="manage_calls_pcode">
    <ComboBox Width="180" DropDownClosed="mc_pcode_DropDownClosed"
      ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.LookUpCollection_6 ,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding MCPostCode}" 
      DisplayMemberPath="Desc" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Instead of setting the ComboBox.DataContext to the parent ListView - the ItemsSoruce is now set directly, allowing you to access the row's 'MCPostCode' value. Unless I've missed something?

Comment: Hi Olitee, Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. Your solution did not work in my case.

Comment: No worries. @Blam has the best approach, placing the data your view needs into your model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution that worked for me.

The Changed DataTemplate for the ComboBox:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="manage_calls_pcode">
        <ComboBox Width="90" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=MCPostCodeX}" DropDownClosed="mc_pcode_DropDownClosed" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MCCodes}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
                  Tag="{Binding Path=MCSIndex}"
                  />
    </DataTemplate>
```

The change to use a Dictionary for the ItemSource for the ComboBox:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> PCodeList = new Dictionary<int,string>();
```

The method used to load the Dictionary

```
        ArrayList lkl = serl.ListLookupsC(0);
        if (lkl.Count > 1)
        {
            LookUpCollection_6.Clear();
            LookUpCollection_7.Clear();
            for (int x = 0; x < lkl.Count; x++)
            {
                string[] strLData = (string[])lkl[x];
                PCodeList.Add(x, strLData[1]);
            }
        }
```

The change to the SalesAgentRec Class

```
        public class SalesAgentRec
    {
        public string MCName { get; set; }
        public string MCPostCode { get; set; }
        public string MCSource { get; set; }
        public string MCUid { get; set; }
        public string MCRecs { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> MCCodes { get; set; }
        public int MCPostCodeX { get; set; }
        public string MCSIndex { get; set; }
    }
```

The method to load the SalesAgentList collection

```
    private void GetSalesAgents()
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
        SerUsers seru = new SerUsers();
        ArrayList al = seru.GetTeleSales();
        _SalesAgentList.Clear();
        if (al.Count == 0)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            return;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < al.Count; x++)
        {
            string[] strData = (string[])al[x];
            int nIndex = -1;
            // Use LINQ to find the key for the value
            if (strData[2].Length == 2)
            {
                var item = (from d in PCodeList
                            where d.Value.Substring(0, 2) == strData[2]
                            select d.Key).FirstOrDefault();

                nIndex = (int)item;
            }
            _SalesAgentList.Add(new SalesAgentRec{
                MCUid = strData[0],
                MCName = strData[1],
                MCPostCode = strData[2],
                MCCodes = PCodeList,
                MCPostCodeX = nIndex,
                MCSIndex = x.ToString()
            });
        }
        this.manage_calls_listView.View = this.manage_calls_listView.FindResource("manage_calls_gridView") as ViewBase;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
```

The above code has not yet been optimized for performance or error handling and has purely been used to test out the answers supplied. The values returned by serl.ListLookupC(0) will be unique due to the nature of the SQL query in that method.

Thanks again to everyone who took the time to reply.